# 0xc00d5212 : No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content

Tags: c++, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation, wmv

I want to implement SinkWriter to encode RGB32 screen frames with Windows Media Video 9 Screen Encoder (MSS2) using Media Foundation. After running the program in Visual Studio 2022, I encountered the following problem when executing `IMFSinkWriter::SetInputMediaType`:

`0xc00d5212 : No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content.`

I think I included all necessary headers and libraries. I also checked that I have WMVSENCD.DLL file in the System32 folder. When I run this code for H264 encoder and MP4 file, it works well. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
HRESULT MediaFoundationScreenRecorder::InitializeSinkWriter(IMFSinkWriter** ppWriter, DWORD* pStreamIndex)
{
    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFSinkWriter* pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
    DWORD streamIndex;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"mfoutput.wmv", NULL, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

    hr |= MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
    hr |= pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    hr |= pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MEDIASUBTYPE_MSS2);
    hr |= pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 800000);
    hr |= pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    hr |= MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, SCALED_VIDEO_WIDTH, SCALED_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    hr |= MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    hr |= MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);

    hr |= pSinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &streamIndex);

    hr |= MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
    hr |= pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    hr |= pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
    hr |= pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    hr |= MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, SCALED_VIDEO_WIDTH, SCALED_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    hr |= MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    hr |= MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);

    hr |= pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);

    hr |= pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
        (*ppWriter)->AddRef();
        *pStreamIndex = streamIndex;
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeOut);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeIn);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Bitwise OR-ing `HRESULT` values is a meaningless (and destructive) operation. Please use proper error handling. The [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) offers error handling macros if you need to keep the code compact.

Comment: I know that. This is purely a test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question boils down to the following: is MSS2 at all a supported format for this API?

Sink Writer is a convenience layer API over encoders and sinks. When you requests a .wmv sink writer, the API creates an [ASF Media Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/asf-media-sinks) internally and then tries to fit the `MFVideoFormat_MSS2` format you requested there.

I am not confident that MSS2 is supported, for example [Windows Media Encoders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/windows-media-encoders) does not mention it as a listed format.

My guess that even if there is a chance to configured the internal pipeline to produce MSS2 recording, for what there is no proof or documentation reference, it might still be unable to achieve this via Sink Writer API.

At least I browsed through MSDN pages a bit, and I don't see an clear statement for codec support even for internal level of pipeline primitives. I would say screen codec is just not a supported scenario for Sink Writer API and you would have to put more of your own effort to get files in this encoding with Media Foundation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since Windows Media Video Screen Encoder is not supported by Sink Writer, how else can I use it? Do you know what components from Media Foundation I should use to properly encode and save the image to file using Windows Media Video Screen Encoder?

Comment: You can create a Media Session instance and add nodes there, with MSS2 transform (obtained e.g. with `MFTEnum`), with ASF sink you preconfigure to accept MSS2. If this is at all possible and it's a question of configuration, this would work. Otherwise you might need to implement your own media sink over lower level WMV/ASF API. Sink Writer creates a Media Session like pipeline internally anyway so you would be doing pretty much what it does on its own, just with more control and flexibility.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it. I will write if I encounter any more problems or if the whole operation is successful.

Comment: Unfortunately, but the MFTEnum function returns an empty array when creating a transform node. I think in this case the encoder is also unsupported.